# C# Automation: To get drop down values and store disable values

Tags: c#, selenium

I want a solution for writing a script for C# Automation using selenium web driver library in TFS, I have to store all disabled values and then click on them. Actually, the validation is like that I should not be able to click on disabled values in a drop-down list. So I need help here in 2 things:

- I want to store disabled values first and then
- I want to iterate through them
- To write a boolean/any function for validation that I am unable to click that values

Here is the code:

```
<select name="ctl00" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl00$\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ctl00_" style="width:200px;">
<option value="1" disabled="disabled">A</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2" enabled="enabled">B</option>
<option value="3" disabled="disabled">C</option>
<option value="4" disabled="disabled">D</option>

</select>
```

So, A, C, and D are the options for which I want validation.
Need a helping hand :)
Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you want a C# solution, why have you tagged VB.NET?

Comment: i am really sorry and Thanks for editing

Comment: Please if anyone can help from C# team

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to search my pages for 'is-loading' classes to check for loading elements. I've reflavored to check for 'disabled' classes, pass them into an array, and then click on the. Not tested but hopefully gets you pointed in the right direction.

```js
new WebDriverWait(driver, MyDefaultTimeout)
.Until(e => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)e)
.ExecuteScript(""+
    "do {"+
        // Find loading element(s)
        "var element = document.getElementsByClassName('disabled');"+
        // Create array of elements
        "var elementList = Array.prototype.slice.call(element);"+
        "if(!elementList === undefined && !elementList == 0) {"+
            // Map Id and Attribute
            "var array = elementList.map(function(v){ return {'ID': v.id} });"+ //"'Attr': v.getAttribute('data-custAtt')"+
            // Output array of disabled objects
            "console.log(array);"+
            // Check to see if array is empty
            "if (!array === undefined && !array.length == 0) {"+
                // Click disabled element
                "var i;"+
                "for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){"+
                  "var disabledElement = array[i];"+
                  "disabledElement.click();}";"+
            "}"+
            "else"+ // Array is empty, exit the loop
            "{"+
                "done = true;"+
            "}"+
        "}"+
        "else"+
        "{"+
            // We may not have an array of elements
            // So if we only have 1
            "if(!element === undefined) {"+
                // Click disabled element
                "element.click();"+
            "}"+
            "else"+
            "{"+
                "done = true;"+
            "}"+
        "}"+
    "}"+
    "while(done = 'false');")
.Equals("complete"));
```

Comment: Thanks but i want little simple code snippet to implement. Still i will try to implement this as well